# Cannot access to report server on reporting service

Tags: reporting-services

I try to open report server but cannot access to report server

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaL2U.png

Comment: Please share the logs from the Reporting Services log files.
Log files location: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Are you running IE as an administrator?